# Revealing module pattern syntax error

Tags: javascript

Maybe this question is not too much constructive but it seems I can figure out why I'm getting this syntax error:

```
 var operations = function () {
            function computeTotalPrice(elem) {
                var totalpriceafter = 0;
                 $(".totalForProductNotDeleted").each(function () {
                    var pp = parseFloat($(this).html().toString().replace(",", "."));
                    totalpriceafter += pp;
                });
                return totalpriceafter;
            };
           function HightLightChangedPrices(elem) {
                elem.parent().parent().parent().find(".totalForProduct").effect("highlight");
                $("#totalPrice").effect("highlight");
            };
            return
            {
                computeTotalPrice : computeTotalPrice,
                HightLightChangedPrices : HightLightChangedPrices / I get expected ; 
            };

        };
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`return` must be followed by a value on the same line.

```
        return
        {
            computeTotalPrice : computeTotalPrice,
            HightLightChangedPrices : HightLightChangedPrices 
        };
```

should be

```
        return {
            computeTotalPrice : computeTotalPrice,
            HightLightChangedPrices : HightLightChangedPrices 
        };
```

The problem is with "restricted productions".  http://es5.github.io/#x5.1.6 says

> If the phrase “[no LineTerminator here]” appears in the right-hand side of a production of the syntactic grammar, it indicates that the production is a restricted production: it may not be used if a LineTerminator occurs in the input stream at the indicated position. For example, the production:
>
> *ReturnStatement* : 
>     `return` *[no LineTerminator here]* *Expression<sub>opt</sub>* `;`

The JavaScript parser sees your code and it parses the first line, a `return` and then a line terminator, so it [inserts a semicolon](http://es5.github.io/#x7.9) and then proceeds to the next line.  It then sees a `{` and interprets that as the beginning of a statement block since a top level [Expression Statement](http://es5.github.io/#x12.4) cannot start with a `{`:

> *ExpressionStatement* : 
>     *[lookahead ∉ {`{`, `function`}] Expression* `;`

Inside the block,

```
 computeTotalPrice : computeTotalPrice, HightLightChangedPrices
```

is a valid [labelled statement](http://es5.github.io/#x12.12), but a statement cannot be validly followed by a `:` which is why it asks for a semicolon there.